# avoid data showed with jquery.html lost after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

when the user starts my app, there is a lot of data coming from a web service which is stored into the device´s database and then shown on the HTML-page using jquery`s .html() method. The problem is when the user selects another HTML page and then comes back, the data is not shown anymore, it has to be read out from the database again.

I know this isn't "rent a coder" but my question is: Is there a way to keep the data persistant on the HTML page even after the page is reloaded? Or do I have to pack everything into a single HTML document?

Comment: you could use the localStorage ?

Comment: I think the use of 2 (database, localstorage with the webservice 3) different data sources will lead to issues and is not a proper data-binding design, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution could be to handle all navigation with AJAX, make your website [a one page app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) and keeps things into cache. But i think this is a really big topic. 
In any case a good Javascript MVC Framework like Backbone or Ember could help you.